# My XAMPP cannot run MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

So I was trying to use XAMPP and it started giving me weird errors. I can't figure out what's causing these kind of errors.Here's what it says:

```
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL settings or
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\program files\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe    --defaults-file=c:\program files\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
2:57:57 PM  [mysql]     Successful!
```

Then, I still click on the START button of mysql and then click Shell, here another error and it says:

```
File:" c:\program files\xampp\xampp_shell.bat" not found.
```

How can I fix this errors?

Comment: Check if  you have MYSQL already running.. If it's not the case, delete everything and try to install again..

Comment: I dont have any mySQL running @Prashanth

Comment: Are you able to browse localhost?